# PHP: how to replace a bbcode-quote with extended data (recursive)?

Tags: php, recursion, replace, bbcode

that's my bbcode for quoting a post (12345 is the id of the original post):

```
[quote=12345] ... citation ... [/quote]
```

I would like to display the quote like this:

```
<blockquote>
    <a href="">Username</a> at 2012-09-12 11:00 a.m. (<a href="">original</a>):
    ... citation ...
</blockquote>
```

**Idea** (pseudocode):

```
$bbcode_content = "[quote=12345] ... citation ... [/quote]";

// 1. get the $post_id
$post_id = replace('/\[quote\=(.*?)\]/is','$1', $bbcode_content);

// 2. select the post data from databse
$post_obj = $DB->select("SELECT `author`, `timestamp` FROM `posts` WHERE id=".$post_id);

// 3. build an extended bbcode tag
$bbcode_content = "[quote post_id={$post_id} timestamp={$post_obj->timestamp} author={$post_obj->author}]";

// 4. bbcode to html
$html = replace("[quote post_id=(*) timestamp=(*) author=(*)]", '<blockquote><a href="">$1</a> at '.date("Y-m-d h:i", $2).' (<a href="forum/post/$3">original</a>)', $bbcode_content);
$html = replace("[/quote]", "</blockquote>", $html);
```

**Problems**:

1. How to replace this stuff recursive? Maybe with [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace-callback.php)?
2. What's the regex for my 4th point "bbcode to html"?

I'm a little bit confused. How would you fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just want to say that if your purpose of using bbcode is to allow markup without introducing xss vulnerabilities, you should not try to code your own bbcode processor. It's deceptively difficult to do correctly, and your code is already rife with security holes. I thought I'd mention this because often if security isn't an issue, its easier to just allow html.

Comment: ^^ Very that.  You really want to use a well-tested third-party library for this.  There are *plenty* of them.

Comment: I'll rethink about coding my own bbcode processor. I didn't thought that would be that extensive. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the [bbcode extension in PHP](http://php.net/bbcode) to take care of this for you.

Comment: Looks nice but it wouldn't work on every webspace. I would like to avoid too much external packages.

Comment: Do you really need it to work on **every webspace**? You have two options: you can chose to sacrifice the possibility that everyone on the planet can run your code out of the box and go for convenience of not having to solve a problem someone else has already solved for you... Or, you can sacrifice your time to make your code super portable and possibly lose a few hairs in the process. It's not that you can't do what you're trying to do it's just that it's only going to get more complicated from here. I'm just trying to save you a lot of time and effort. It's very easy to install the extension

Comment: I know, you're right. I actually try to avoid using extensions, but your way seems to be a good one. I'll try it. :)

Comment: How about parsing the following strings ? 

 [quote][quote] This is a test [url] google.com.hk [/url] and [img] abc.com/test.png [/img] [/quote][/quote] 

Are there any API for parsing bbcodes using java especially dealing with the recursive BBCodes ?